# Can you make multiple "if" conditions in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

In JavaScript, one could do this:

```
if (integer > 3 && integer < 34){
    document.write("Something")
}
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Python indeed allows you to do such a thing

```
if integer > 3 and integer < 34
```

Python is also smart enough to handle:

```
if 3 < integer < 34:
    # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 13):

Python replaces the usual C-style boolean operators (`&&`, `||`, `!`) with words: `and`, `or`, and `not` respectively.

So you can do things like:

```
if (isLarge and isHappy) or (isSmall and not isBlue):
```

which makes things more readable.

Comment: In C++, you can actually use `and` and `or` in place of `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Indeed!  I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 11):

Just on formatting. If you have very long conditions, I like this way of formatting

```
if (isLarge and isHappy) \
or (isSmall and not isBlue):
     pass
```

It fits in nicely with Python's comb formatting

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to split things up.

Comment: Using \ can be dangerous. I'd wrap the conditions in an outer set of parens

Comment: foosion's right, it's better to use an extra set of parentheses and break the line while that extra set is open than to use a backslash. See "Maximum Line Length" at [PEP 8: Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @foosion why using \ can be dangerous  ?

Answer (score 5):

```
if integer > 3 and integer < 34:
    # do work
```

Answer (score 3):

yes like this:

```
if 3 < integer < 34:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is:

```
if integer > 3 and integer < 34:
   document.write("something")
```