# I'm getting':' expected error even if It's there

Tags: python-3.x

```
if ccsorgu<=1600,otvsorgu=="araba":  <----
otv=45/100
if ccsorgu<=2000,ccsorgu>>1600,otvsorgu=="araba":  <----
otv=130/100
```

File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 7
if ccsorgu<=1600,otvsorgu=="araba":
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please post the `Traceback`.

Comment: Your problem is the `,` in the if, you need either `and` or `or`. Does this answer your question? [Can you make multiple "if" conditions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809698/can-you-make-multiple-if-conditions-in-python)

Comment: And what do you want with `>>`?

Comment: I wasn't notice '>>' in first time then i saw its working that way too. I'm just lazy

Answer (score 0):

python if condition dont use `,` as separator.

this is wrong `if ccsorgu<=1600 , otvsorgu=="araba":`

it should be `if ccsorgu<=1600 or otvsorgu=="araba":`
or
`if ccsorgu<=1600 and otvsorgu=="araba":`